# Javascript or Ajax like counter

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there possible to make a javascript or an ajax like counter that doesn't reset to 0 when refreshed?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
function countClicks() {
count = count + 1;
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = count;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<a href="javascript:countClicks();">Count Clicks</a>
</p>
<p id="p2">0</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` to persist data on the client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  localStorage.clickCount = localStorage.clickCount || 0;
  function countClicks() {
    localStorage.clickCount++;
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = localStorage.clickCount;
  }
</script>
```

When a specific browser accesses the page for the first time, it will set the `localStorage.clickCount` varibale to 0. Everytime the user of the browser clicks the button, this variable will be incremented and saved in the browser.

If you want to have a count that is shared between all viewers of the page, you will have to implement server-side persistence. Whatever backend you are using will have to implement getting and setting the value of the click count.

Comment: Just to make sure @user2505070 understands what's happening here, the clicks are **not** shared between users (or browsers). It will count how many times **you** clicked the button.

Comment: You are right, the question is vague enough that I didn't realize there were many interpretations to "does not reset"

Comment: My mistake, I should have specified. The ideea is to be shared between users, anyway thank you for the response